# Cannot connect to mosquitto broker from local web client on windows

Tags: javascript, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to connect to mosquitto windows broker service on my machine through javascript. I understand that Paho javascript client connects only through websockets and mosquitto for windows doesn't support websockets unless you build it yourself. My question is that since I am trying to connect to localhost should it matter to have a websockets enabled mqtt broker? Is there any  way to connect to a local mqtt server without using websockets through javascript? And is it unsafe to do so or is it fine since I am connecting to a local server itself?

Thanks in advance for the answer and sorry if it sounds lame to you. I am extremely new to this space.

Answer (score 0):

Even when connecting to localhost you still need websockets support to use the paho JavaScript support.

There are some small apps that will set up a separate websocket listener and bridge that to pure native MQTT e.g.

- http://hai-ng.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/setting-up-mqtt-websocket-gateway-with.html

Comment: Thank you for you response. I have managed to rebuild mosquitto with websockets and solved my problem for now. But your solution does seem very interesting! Thanks again.